# Binding implementations to Request/Response in Laravel?

Tags: php, symfony, oop, laravel, code-injection

**The Problem**

I'm currently building a small library that will allow me to pass information to a Factory class, which then makes a 'RestfulResponse' instance.

I'm attempting to build this library to be framework agnostic, meaning I can use this in projects other than Laravel.

The RestfulResponse is concerned with handling the Response to the client. I want to use Laravel/Symfony's Response class, however, to keep it framework agnostic, the Response class can't be concrete.

I could use Laravel's IoC Container to import the class, however for that to work the Response class needs to implement an interface, which it does not.

**Is there any way, either through Laravel's IoC container, or through some other PHP trickery, I can get this to work? Note: I am using constructor dependency injection, not Facades.**

---

**Code examples**

This code example works, but is not framework-agnostic.

Essentially, I need to find a way to make it framework agnostic, while still relying on Laravel's Response class.

Laravel's Response Class

```
namespace Illuminate\Http;

class Response
{}
```

My Factory Class

```
namespace App\Restful;

class RestfulResponseFactory
{

    protected $restfulResponse;

    public __constructor(RestfulResponse $restfulResponse)
    {
        $this->restfulResponse = $restfulResponse;
    }

}
```

The RestfulResponse Class

```
namespace App\Restful;

use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class RestfulResponse
{

    protected $response;

    public __constructor(Response $response)
    {
        $this->response = $response;
    }

}
```

Static dependency injection (Laravel's Container handles this)

```
namespace App\Restful;

use Illuminate\Http\Response;

$factory = new RestfulResponseFactory(
    new RestfulResponse(new Response)
);
```

Comment: Short answer is no.  The Symfony folks have consistently denied any attempt to create Request/Response interfaces.  They say it's a bad thing.  There is however a PSR7 interface http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/ that is ever so slowly catching on.  It is probably the closest thing you will find to an agnostic interface.  Don't know about Laravel but the Symfony framework has a bridge http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/psr7.html that converts between the Symfony request/response objects and a psr7 implementation.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware of PSR-7 or the bridging. Apparently Laravel does allow you to use the symfony bridge (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#psr7-requests), so I'm going to give that a go, and if it works post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Hope you don't mind but I've posted an answer since I had a lot to say about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally have a working implementation of this, and the solution is fairly straight forward. Laravel has built in support for PSR-7 interfaces, which define a standardized way for representing HTTP messages.

This means that you can 'switch on' PSR-7 request/response interfaces by simply requiring two additional packages in composer:

```
composer require symfony/psr-http-message-bridge
composer require zendframework/zend-diactoros
```

These packages allow you to use PSR-7 interfaces to generate Requests and Responses. The best part about it is that Laravel has already set up a service provider to bind requests for PSR-7 interfaces with the zend implementation. If you're interested the service provider is class is `Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider`.

To implement a PSR-7 response interface simply include `Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface` as a dependency and let Laravel's container handle the concrete implementation.

The final framework-agnostic result will look something like this:

```
namespace App\Restful;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

class RestfulResponse
{

    protected $response;

    public __constructor(ResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $this->response = $response;
    }

}
```

The main issue I came across while trying to implement PSR-7 responses is that the API is different to Laravel's, which takes a little bit of a learning curve. However, it is very well documented through comments so you can use those to learn the API.

Creating a response requires the first parameter of the constructor to be a `Stream`, not a string. You can easily create a stream by using `fopen`:

```
$stream = fopen('php://memory, 'wb+');
fwrite($stream, 'Hello, world.');
```

Thanks to **Cerad** for pointing me in the right direction of using PSR-7 with Symfony Framework's bridge.

Comment: tahnks for your auto-response. you don't have problems with middlewares? I have a problem when a middleware return PSR-7 response. When psr-7 response is on controller, I don't have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this bridging did not work for me, as one of the commenters said. Everything goes fine with the controller domain (e.g. tests) but when curling it complains about a malformed chunked response.

Since tampering with content headers is not a good idea I am doing something along these lines:

```php
class RestfulResponse
{

    protected $response;

    public function __construct(ResponseInterface $response) {
      $this->response = $response;  
    }

    public function toLaravelResponse() {
      $statusCode = $this->response->getStatusCode();
      if ($statusCode == 200) {
          return response($this->response->getBody()->getContents());
      }
      else {
          return response($this->response->getReasonPhrase(), $statusCode);
      }
    }

}
```